# Is it possible for an if statement to equal multiple possibilities C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

is it possible for an if then statement to be equal to multiple possibilities?

for example

```
if(option1 == "a","b","c");
```

?

Comment: Something like that `could` be implemented for `Custom Types` via `Operator Overloading`, however I think it's a terribly bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

I often wish for the same thing, this is what I do sometimes:

```
string[] optionOneVals = new string[3] {"a", "b", "c"};

if (optionOneVals.Contains(option1)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: oh ok so you're putting it into an array

Comment: +1. Note: if you check similar questions you'll find recommendation to use `HashSet`/`Dictionary` if list is large. Or you can inline it into `if` too: `if (new string[]{"a", "b", "c"}.Contains(option1))...`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks!  I generally don't need to do it (I usually just use ORs).  However, this approach proved handy for me when I did some SharePoint programming with event receivers.  You basically have one event receiver function for many types of lists, and you want to do different things for different lists, so I'll put my like list identifiers in a static array of strings and structure the event receiver with a series of Contains checks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it one of two ways.  You can check each case separately with the boolean or `||` operator:

```
if (option1 == "a" || option1 == "b" || etc...)
```

or you can create a collection of choices and see if it contains the variable you're testing:

```
if (new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }.Contains(option1))
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want that `option1` have to be  `1` or `2` or `3` you have to do this:

```
if (option1 == 1 || option1 == 2 || option1 == 3)
```